# Display facebook comments in different style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, plugins

I want to display facebook comments on a web page but facebook comment plugin is comes with facebook style. Is it possible to remove everything except the facebook comment text?

Or is there some other js/jquery plugins or code that would pull only facebook comments so I can display them.

Any help or hint is very appreciated!

Comment: Facebook comments are displayed in an `iframe` so you won't be able to alter their appearance using a client-side library.

Comment: It's complicated, but you might be able to use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed) to get what you want.

Comment: The "other way" is to use some css and overlap the facebook iframe with your desired design. I think it could be little difficult... But possible.

Comment: @kmsdev No, you can't use CSS to modify styles on another site's content in an iframe.

Comment: @Blazemonger I am talking about positioned elements overlapping the iframe. If I can, later (or tomorrow), I will answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I commented above, here is an example explaining how I think that you can do. Obviously this is limited but also useful:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/ms99o6ae/)

```
// HTML

<div class="relative">
    <div class="overlap">
        <div class="box a"><p>You have to imagine that this is the facebook plugin</p></div>
        <div class="box b"></div>
        <div class="box c">IPSUM dolor and sit then amet</div>
        <div class="box d"></div>
        <div class="box e"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://en.lipsum.com"></iframe>
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="show/hide overlaps" />


// CSS

*:not(input) { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
iframe { width: 350px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; border: solid 1px lightblue; }
.relative { position: relative; width: 350px; height: 350px; } 
.overlap { display: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
.box { position: absolute; background: white; text-align: center; }

.a { left: 0; width: 100%; height: 105px; background: lightgreen; }
.a p { font: normal 14px/105px Tahoma, sans-serif; color: #666; }
.b { left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 57px; height: 114px; }
.c { left: 108px; bottom: 90px; width: 225px; height: 20px; font: normal 15px Arial, sans-serif; color: red; text-align: left; }
.d { left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 87px; background: lightgreen; }


// JS

$('input').on('click', function(){
    $('.overlap').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Does it only work with iframes? facebook gives me:  "<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="1" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>"

Anyway this method certainly isnt perfect but might help on some occasions.

Comment: It's an idea more than a method or a concept. It could be useful for iframes if you can not modify its elements but you can use it when or where you want. As you can see, it's only some positioned divs on the iframe, so it could work depending the target.